# If statement in Access macro not seeing table in same database

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, macros

Access 2016
I feel like a high schooler who has forgotten how a period works in a sentence.

I have a blank database. I create 1 table named TestTable. One column called Amplitude with one record 14.

[image: I create a macro.]

It says "Microsoft Access cannot find the name TestTable you entered" Error 2482. I've googled and searched on here, as far as I can tell I am using the correct syntax. Granted this is the first time I've used If statements directly in the macro form (I usually convert to a module) so maybe I just don't know some quirk about the If statement field, but I've looked at tutorials for macros and If then blocks and I've seen sample code with people using the same syntax. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Cannot reference table or query directly, even if there is only one record. Use DLookup() or DCount().

Comment: what a weird thing requirement. thank you June

Comment: Imagine that you are given a letter file and asked if it was this month's telephone bill. You will have to open the file ("table") and navigate to a specific letter ("record") to anwer the question for that particular item.

Comment: Why is that a weird requirement? What if there were multiple records? How should the code know which record you want? Just because there is only one record doesn't change the method.

Comment: This is why Macros are the Devil's handiwork.  ;o)  If you wrote this in code, it'd have been easier.

Comment: Its weird because you have to use a function for a database to look into its own assets and there could be further syntax for looking at the records past the first. in this instance I only needed it to assess the first spot. but I do take your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per June7

Cannot reference table or query directly, even if there is only one record. Use DLookup() or DCount().